# Qt QML RoundButton icon doesn't fill the item

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

When displaying an svg image inside a RoundButton, I end up with a fixed width (grey) border (the svg doesn't fill the button).

The icon I am using is round; the svg size is set to match that image.
I have tried:

- adding `background: undefined`: removes the grey border (but doesn't fix the icon size), so what we are seeing is the grey background.
- modifying the button's size: the border seems to always be the same width, so it looks like a fixed margin is being assigned
- changing the icon to be a square: same effect, the border on top, bottom, sides seems to be of fixed size. Depending on the button size, the square is going to be contained within the button, or "stick out".

```
    RoundButton {
      height: 45
      width: height
      anchors.top: parent.top
      anchors.right: parent.right
      icon.source: "qrc:/images/controls/roundInfo.svg"
      icon.height: height
      icon.width: width
    }
```

How do I get rid of this margin around my icon?

---

Providing a simplified svg file for testing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="10.6mm" height="10.6mm" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 10.6 10.6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <path transform="scale(.265)" d="m20 0c-7.4-3.71e-7 -13.9 4.05-17.3 10.1h34.7c-3.46-6-9.92-10.1-17.3-10.1zm-17.4 10.1c-1.69 2.93-2.67 6.32-2.67 9.95-3.32e-6 11 8.96 20 20 20l-17.4-30zm17.4 30c11 0 20-8.96 20-20 1e-6 -3.62-0.983-7.01-2.67-9.95l-17.4 30z" fill-rule="evenodd" style="paint-order:normal"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Try to play with `spacing` or `padding`. BTW it would be helpful to have that svg (or similar) so that we can try to reproduce ourselves

Comment: Yes, thank you! Padding is the key. Your pointer also helped me to find more information in the Qt help, which I just realized I was not using to its full potential. You can enter this as an answer, if you want the credits...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `IconLabel` is the `contentItem` of the `RoundButton`. The `contentItem` will get padded by the specified `padding` property. By default this value is 12, which makes the `IconLabel` 12 pixels smaller on each site, (so 24 in total per direction).

*Note that this only works if the icon width and height are set to the size of the button since otherwise the images is just centered in the button again*

```
RoundButton {
    height: 45
    width: width

    icon.source: "qrc:/image.svg"
    icon.height: height
    icon.width: width

    padding: 0 //the trick
}
```

You can find out by looking at the QML files which you get when you install Qt (not even the source-variant): `<path to>/Qt/5.12.3/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls.2/RoundButton.qml`